# Unable to find Image File Path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

so I have been scratching my head over this for a day or so now.

So, on my page, I have a v-for that cycles through a .json file, grabs the name and displays it as an image with the same name, from the assets/sub-folder/image.png

I pass it in like so

```
<img
 :src="
  require(`@/assets/images/folderone/${image1}.png`)
 "
/>
```

and that works fine.

However, I do this again later on, with a folder I have edited the names of (turning from capital to lowercase) (not sure if this has any impact) like so:

```
<img
 :src="
  require(`@/assets/images/foldertwo/${image2}.png`)
 "
/>
```

and it works on my local host, but after pushing it live, it cannot find "/image2.53g2d62.png"

So, I went ahead and duplicated my foldertwo and called it "foldertest" and instead done the same thing, grabbing from that new folder instead. and... it works....

Is there something I need to do/can do when an image is struggling to be found in a folder, after some sort of renaming-task? As it honestly seems to me like somewhere, it saved this path and doesn't always update/allow it to be findable?

Comment: Might just be a simple caching issue? Have you tried disabling your browser's cache? You should also make sure to hard refresh the page after these kind of changes (ctrl + shift + r), sometimes these sorts of changes don't get picked up by HMR